# How to organize a relatively large amount of mobx stores

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Currently, I have a mobx structure:

- Page Stores. Stores for the each app route(handle forms, route onEnter and onLeave).
- Domain Stores. Stores to
  manipulate and keep data from a server(Sync with the server, parse, keep arrays with data models).
- Data models. Models(Store) to keep and describe a particular data instance.

Right now my init stores js looks like:

```
const initStores = (apolloClient) => {
  const appStore = new AppStore(apolloClient),
        // Data Stores
        uploadStore = new UploadStore(appStore),
        collectionGroupsStore = new CollectionGroupsStore(appStore),
        collectionsStore = new CollectionsStore({appStore, uploadStore, collectionGroupsStore}),
        imagesStore = new ImagesStore({appStore}),


        // Pages
        indexPageStore = new IndexPageStore({appStore, uploadStore, collectionsStore, collectionGroupsStore}),
        collectionPageStore = new CollectionPageStore(appStore, uploadStore),
        loginStore = new LoginStore(appStore),
        publicUserStore = new PublicUserStore(appStore),
        userSettingsStore = new UserSettingsStore(appStore);

  collectionGroupsStore.injectStores({collectionsStore})

  return {
    appStore,
    uploadStore,
    collectionsStore,
    collectionGroupsStore,
    indexPageStore,
    collectionPageStore,
    loginStore,
    publicUserStore,
    userSettingsStore,
  }

}

const stores = initStores(apolloClient)

export default stores;
```

The problem is that Domain stores(collectionGroupsStore, collectionsStore, imagesStore) need to be linked to each other and share the data between them. It seems that more domain stores I have, more boilerplate I will write. Am I missing something? Is there any better way to organize stores and make them speak to each other?

**EDIT:** I think I optimized my initial config a bit:

```
const initStores = (apolloClient) => {
  // Data Stores
  const dataStores = {
    appStore: new AppStore(apolloClient),
    uploadStore: new UploadStore(),
    collectionGroupsStore: new CollectionGroupsStore(),
    collectionsStore: new CollectionsStore(),
  }

  for (let prop in dataStores) {
    if (dataStores[prop].injectStores) dataStores[prop].injectStores({...dataStores})
  }

  // Pages
  const pageStores = {
    indexPageStore: new IndexPageStore({...dataStores}),
    collectionPageStore: new CollectionPageStore({...dataStores}),
    loginStore: new LoginStore({...dataStores}),
    publicUserStore: new PublicUserStore({...dataStores}),
    userSettingsStore: new UserSettingsStore({...dataStores}),
  }

  return {
    ...dataStores,
    ...pageStores
  }
}
```